# Can I use forked git repository to dependency by jitpack on android studio

Tags: git, gradle, jitpack

here is grale file.

build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files

    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle ( Module: app)

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.3.9'

// https://mvnrepository.com/art.../commons-codec/commons-codec
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'

compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.Kernelzero:androidtiffbitmapfactory:1.0'
// compile 'com.github.beyka:androidtiffbitmapfactory:0.9.1'
}
```

---

I did register forked git project on jitpack

but I received error log.

Failed to resolve : com.github.Kernerlzero:androidtiffbitmapfactory:1.0

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues

1. The dependency should be: `com.github.Kernelzero:Android-TiffBitmapFactory:1.0`
2. The project has a build error at that version. More details in the log https://jitpack.io/com/github/Kernelzero/Android-TiffBitmapFactory/1.0/build.log

To find new build logs open:
https://jitpack.io/#Kernelzero/Android-TiffBitmapFactory